# How to use a Url having special characters in HttpGet(URL) in java

Tags: java

I am using HttpClient, its working fine for any url having no special characters.

But when i send the url having special characters it gets failed.

I tried URL Api but it is deprecated.

Tried with utf-8 but also did not work.

Can you suggest me a simple way of making the HttpGet call for below url

http://example.com/?status!~^(notdeleted|presesnt)$&env~check_test

Comment: Have you looked at `URLEncodedUtils.parse()` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
String link = "http://example.com/?"
    + URLEncoder.encode("status!~^(notdeleted|presesnt)$&env~check_test", "UTF-8");
```

Maybe in two parts around `&` if that is meant as the next URL parameter.

Comment: above not worked, started getting exception:

org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException

Comment: Any answer on this